# Exchange mailbox: Send via "Send as" but with use of own name

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange

We have the following mailbox:
mail: customerservice@ourcompany.com
Label: Cutomer Service

Two staff members have "Send as" authorization.
When they send an email it appears as "Customer Service
customerservice@ourcompany.com" in our customers mailbox.

We want the follwing: 
"Bob Smith customerservice@ourcompany.com" if Bob Smith sends an Email
"Nico Pearson customerservice@ourcompany.com" if Nico Pearson sends an Email

We don't want to use the "Bob Smith on behalf of Customer Service" option.

Is this feasible and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, it is impossible to achieve that. I found [a similar thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/40338/how-can-i-remove-the-on-behalf-of-message-when-sending-from-a-delegated-accoun), in which @Rubén♦ provided a workaround: delegated account could be added to the delegate mailbox as another email address or alias. Maybe you could check if it could be useful to you.